# Border at top and left hand side of page with background image

Tags: html, css

I am putting together a pretty basic website at the moment just as part of my university coursework.  I've put in a background image and it nearly fits perfectly - however for some reason I have a white margin at the top of the image (about an inch thick) and a white margin to the left (about half an inch).

here's my css for the image:

```css
    #image {

     width: 100% 100%;
     position: fixed;
     z-index: -9;
     opacity: 0.8;
     display: block;
     background-size: cover;
 }
```

I have placed the background image in the html just after the opening body tag as this:

```
    <img id="image" src="CourseworkImages/background2.jpg" alt="Background Image">
```

I have no idea why I have these margins on the page and they are ruining the look of the page - any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Hey! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question could use a little more code to enable us to help you. Please read here to see how to create a [MCVE].

Comment: Is there a reason you're using an `img` instead of using CSS? Something like `body { background-image: url( '/path/to/image.jpg' );`.

Comment: `html, body {padding: 0, margin: 0}`

Comment: @ovokuro any solid reason for using `padding: 0;` on `html` and `body`? Being uber cautious? Just curious. Never seen default padding used on either.

Comment: use `background` property of `body` element instead.

Comment: @hungerstar - that has fixed the issue.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @Conor I've added comment as answer. Did you leave in all your other CSS properties? If you did, you probably don't need most of them.

Comment: @hungerstar Probably just habit. You're right, not sure if padding would make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an `img` tag like you have I would suggest using CSS. Something like:

```
body {
  background-image: url( '/path/to/image.jpg' );
}
```

You can get rid of a lot of the properties you were using with this approach. The one you'll likely want to keep is `background-size`.

As others have pointed out, most browsers add `8px` of margin to the `body` element which creates unwanted white space. To remove that, add `margin: 0;` to the CSS selector above.

---

To keep the opacity I would use a pseudo element on the body. You could also create a PNG with the desired opacity built in. Using CSS is a bit more flexible.

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: hotpink;
}

body:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.6;
  background-image: url( 'http://placekitten.com/1600/1600' );
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: this worked - thanks so much.  Quick followup question; how do I now alter the properties of the background image?  I want to change the opacity but not sure how to do it now that it's all in the CSS...

Comment: You can either create the image with the opacity built in using PNG or you can do something similar to what you started with but using pseudo elements instead. I'll update in a few minutes.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty basic example:

```
body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     border: 1px solid yellow;
     border-right-style: none;
     border-bottom-style: none;
     width: 100%;
     opacity: 0.8;
     display: block;
     background-size: cover;
     background-image: url("CourseworkImages/background2.jpg");
}
```

You could also do it with a wrapper div. You may also need to play around with `background-position` and `repeat` properties. And you also need to reset the browser default margins and paddings in order get really no space between. As I said, basic example. If you are interested in this topic, you could look at css frameworks, that resets all browser-predefined styles, e. g. normalize.css

Comment: Adding `opacity` to the `body` will cause all descendant elements to share that opacity, [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1mbjdvr0/). Not to mention not affecting the background image's opacity.

Comment: well, I just copied every properties from the questioner. However, this answer should solve the question.

Comment: Blindly copying properties is not a defense for a solution that **doesn't** solve the question. In [**your solution**](https://jsfiddle.net/1mbjdvr0/1/) all content of `body` has opacity applied to it (not good) and the background image does not have opacity/transparency as you cannot see any of the yellow background through the image (not what OP wants).